# How to install a plugin in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

This seems like a stupid question but [this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/plugins/) does not specify how to actually open a screen in IntelliJ which allows you to install a plugin.  Is it even possible in the community edition?

Answer (score 14):

From your link

> A convenient UI helps you install any available plugin from the Plugin Repository without leaving IntelliJ IDEA. (IDE Settings | Plugins):

```
File
   |_ Settings...
           |_ IDE Settings
                     |_ Plugins.
```

Here's a screenshot of the Settings dialog with Plugins selected:

[image]

Edit: Not sure if this is available in the community edition; I'm using Ultimate 12.0.4

Comment: it's actually under `IntelliJ IDEA` -> `Preferences` -> `IDE Settings`.  I am on a Mac

Comment: Haha. Thanks. Good to know about the Mac location, I obviously was doing this in Windows.

Comment: Just a heads up, installing every plugin in the universe slows down intellij. More is less...

Comment: On a Mac as of IntelliJ 2017.1, choose `Preferences` > `Plugins`. You can find, download, and install a plugin from a single panel.

Comment: On a Mac, IntelliJ 2023, it's `IntelliJ IDEA` > `Settings...` > `Plugins`